# Wikipedia API: How to get the City of a Place / Page / Article

Tags: wikipedia-api

I want to get the city of [Eiffel Tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_Tower) Page by using Wikipedia API.

I used below code to get the Abstract Intro, WikiPageID, WikiURL, Thumbnail/Image, WikiDataID & Coordinates of wiki title [Eiffel_Tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Eiffel_Tower&prop=extracts%7Cinfo%7Cpageimages%7Ccoordinates%7Cpageprops&exintro&explaintext&redirects&inprop=url).

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Eiffel_Tower&prop=extracts|info|pageimages|coordinates|pageprops&exintro&explaintext&redirects&inprop=url
```

How could I get the Parent of Places?

Suppose I want City / District / State / Country of Wikipedia Places Page.

For [Eiffel Tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_Tower) page Wikipedia show Location detail as in [Paris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris) [City] and [France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France) [Country].

Answer (score 1):

First find the Wikidata ID of the article (manually by following the "Wikidata item" link in the sidebar, programmatically e.g. by using the [`action=query&prop=pageprops`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageprops&titles=Eiffel_Tower) API module), then use the [Wikidata Query Service](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service) , e.g.

[`SELECT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE { wd:Q243 wdt:P17|wdt:P131 ?item }`](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20wd%3AQ243%20wdt%3AP17%7Cwdt%3AP131%20%3Fitem%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%7D)

Comment: Is it possible to get Country or City of page by using Wikipedia API only?

Comment: No. You can use the MediaWiki API of Wikidata.org but you aren't really better off with that.